# text in textview is not saving if i kill the activity?

Tags: java, android

Iam a new bee to android and I created a small app which should count number of days I attend the class and number of days I dont.But as soon as I kill the app and reopen the text in textview goes back to default

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button b1,b2,b3;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
int i=0;
int j=0;
int nd=0;
Products products;
MyDBHandler myDBHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDBHandler = new MyDBHandler(MainActivity.this,null,null,1);
    products = new Products("Present:"+i,"Absent:" + j,"Percentage" + nd +       "%");
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.percentage);
    products.set_present("Present:"+i);
    products.set_absent("Absent:" + j);
    products.set_percentage("Percentage" + nd + "%");
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            i++;
            tv1.setText("Present:"+i);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            j++;
            tv2.setText("Absent:"+j);
        }
    });
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int dmator=i+j;
    nd=(i*100)/dmator;
    tv3.setText("Percentage:"+nd+"%");

   if(nd>65)
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Chill you are     safe",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(nd<65)
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Attention youre attendance is less     than 65",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});


}


}`//three buttons

//three text views
```

Comment: You have to persist the data. Take a look at `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Preference to save your data . Check if the app is running for first time or save a boo which check if any data was entered last time or not. Which ever way you like. Below is a short Preference class which I could come up with

```
public class PreferenceValues {

private boolean isFirstRun;


private String daysPresent;
private String daysAbsent;
private String percentage;


private Editor ed;


private static PreferenceValues mInstance = null;


private static SharedPreferences prefs;

private PreferenceValues(Context context) {
    super();
}

/**
 * Creating a singleton insatnce of the class
 * 
 * @param ctx
 * @return instance of the class
 */
public static PreferenceValues getInstance() {
    Context ctx = MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new PreferenceValues(ctx);
    }
    prefs = ctx
            .getSharedPreferences("MyPreferencess", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return mInstance;
}

/**
 * To check if the application is running for the first time
 * 
 * @return
 */
public boolean isFirstRun() {
    return prefs.getBoolean("isfirstruns", true);

}

/**
 * To update the flag for the first run
 * 
 * @param isFirstRun
 */
public void setIsFirstRun(Boolean isFirstRun) {
    this.isFirstRun = isFirstRun;
    ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putBoolean("isfirstruns", this.isFirstRun);
    ed.commit();
}


public String getDaysPresent() {
    return prefs.getString("daysPresent", "0");
}

public void setDaysPresent(String daysPresent) {
    this.daysPresent = daysPresent;
    ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString("daysPresent", this.daysPresent);
    ed.commit();
}

public String getdaysAbsent() {
    return prefs.getString("daysAbsent", "0");
}

public void setdaysAbsent(String daysAbsent) {
    this.daysAbsent = daysAbsent;
    ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString("daysAbsent", this.daysAbsent);
    ed.commit();
}

public String getpercentage() {
    return prefs.getString("percentage", "0.00");
}

public void setpercentage(String percentage) {
    this.percentage = percentage;
    ed = prefs.edit();
    ed.putString("percentage", this.percentage);
    ed.commit();

}

}
```

Take this sample Activity code

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btn;
EditText t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    t1.setText(PreferenceValues.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDaysPresent());

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            PreferenceValues.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setDaysPresent(t1.getText().toString());

        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    PreferenceValues.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).setDaysPresent(t1.getText().toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Am glad you came up with something useful I came to know that I should use Sharedpreferences but i dont understand how I can give inputs and take outputs as soon as my activity starts. Ill go through any tutorial. Thanks!

Comment: use following line when your activity starts

Comment: use following line when your activity starts if(PreferenceValues.getContext(). getDaysPresent().equals("0")){t1.setText("") } else{t1.setText(PreferenceValues.getContext(). getDaysPresent())} what this will do is .. It will check if the last value is 0 or not in case its not it will show the value saved last time.  To save the value on buttonClick use PreferenceValue.getContext.setDaysPresent("Your value which you need to save"). Additionally u could also save d same in when ur back btn is pressed or in onPause() in case if you are not hitting any btn and using back or home btn to exit the app

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store data after the app is closed, you need to use SharedPreferences.

See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

and

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Thanks thats a nice tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the activity is killed, so when it's created again, all objects are initialized again. You could cache this data in SharedPreferences, or in a database for example.